# What is the best way to get the start of Half Hour in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> Like 2:46:44 PM should get me 2:30:00 PM,
>            3:25:33 AM should get me 3:00:00 AM SO on.
>           I could do

```
var totalseconds = ((time.getMinutes()* 60) +time.getSeconds());
if(totalseconds>(30*60))
{
  time.setMinutes(30);
}
else
{
  time.setMinutes(00);
}
time.setSeconds(00);
```

Looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: are you able to utilize the `moment.js` library?

Comment: time.setMinutes(Math.floor(time.getMinutes() / 30) * 30); is different, not necessarily better

Comment: If you are already using moment.js, I would recommend looking at the moment-round plugin. It allows you to round, floor, ceil in any increment you desire.

Comment: @ abc123: Nope. I cannot use moment.js 
@Joel : Agreed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//Like 2:46:44 PM should get me 2:30:00 PM, 3:25:33 AM should get me 3:00:00 AM SO on. I could do

var time = new Date();
var mins = time.getMinutes();
var diff = mins % 30;
time.setMinutes(mins - diff);
time.setSeconds(0);
console.log(time);
```

You can use the code as mentioned above.

Comment: I  have used the ? operator instead of if, else.
but I like this approach.